# Animate views(layers) using CAKeyframeAnimation in a loop and CAAnimationGroup

Tags: ios, animation, view, timing, cakeyframeanimation

I am trying to animate several views (layers) using CAKeyframeAnimation and CAAnimationGroup. Each view to be animated is contained in an array. My idea is to loop through the array where CAKeyframeAnimation instance of each view would be added to an array of animations, which then would be added to the CAAnimationGroup. My goal is to animate each view one after another. As far as I understand I need to use the group in order to have a reference for the beginTime.

I am probably missing something obvious, but my code doesn't work

```
CAAnimationGroup *cardAnimationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
cardAnimationGroup.delegate = self;
cardAnimationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
cardAnimationGroup.beginTime = 0.0f;
[cardAnimationGroup setValue:@"animation0" forKey:@"id"];
cardAnimationGroup.duration = 1.2f * [_myViewsArray count];

NSMutableArray *animationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// Loop through views
for (UIView *cardView in _myViewsArray)
{

    NSUInteger index = [_myViewsArray indexOfObject:cardView];
    // my target origin
    CGFloat yOffset = (-(cardView.frame.origin.y - _middleCardView.frame.origin.y) - index * 2);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *translateCardPositionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    translateCardPositionAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    //translateCardPositionAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    translateCardPositionAnimation.beginTime = 1.2f * index;
    translateCardPositionAnimation.duration = 1.2f;

    translateCardPositionAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:yOffset],
                                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:yOffset],nil];

    translateCardPositionAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2f], nil];


    [_containerCardView addSubview:cardView];
    [_containerCardView sendSubviewToBack:cardView];

    [animationsArray addObject:translateCardPositionAnimation];
    [cardView.layer addObject:translateCardPositionAnimation forKey:@"id"];

    if (index == [_myViewsArray count]-1) {
        [cardAnimationGroup setAnimations:animationsArray];

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems you are missing the current time when setting the begin time. Try using `translateCardPositionAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.2f * index;`

Comment: Thanks that helps. But I am just doubting if that is the way to do it.

Comment: You almost always specify `beginTime` as current time + delay if that is what you were asking. Does the animation work when you do that?

Comment: Yes it does work. But maybe I don't really need the group. I haven't tried yet, but if I just loop the CAKeyframeAnimation with `beginTime =  CurrentMediaTime() + offset`, perhaps it would do the same.. The whole idea of the group was that it gives a reference since when to count beginTime, right?